# How to calculate the probability of success of a Logistic Regression model with a single continuous predictor?

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation, model

I have a logistic regression model below, predicting a dichotomous variable *type* from a single continuous predictor *fatigue*. Using the coefficients below I can obtain the increase in the odds of a positive *type* from a 1 unit increase in fatigue.

Also I believe by forming the model expression

```
logit(type) = 0.3134 - 91.1171 * fatigue
```

I can obtain the odds of a positive *type* for a given value of *fatigue* by plugging it in, say for a value *fatigue* = 1.

**However**, what I want to do is to obtain the odds of a positive *type* for a range of *fatigue* values, i.e. **<= 0**. Is this possible?

```
## Call:
## glm(formula = type ~ fatigue, family = binomial(), data = myData)

## Deviance Residuals:
## Min 1Q Median 3Q Max
## -1.6703 -1.3104 0.8369 1.0049 1.4695
##
## Coefficients:
## Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## (Intercept) 0.3134 0.1496 2.095 0.0362 *
## fatigue -91.1171 36.3785 -2.505 0.0123 *
## ---
## Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
##
## (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
##
## Null deviance: 282.84 on 210 degrees of freedom
## Residual deviance: 276.03 on 209 degrees of freedom
## AIC: 280.03
##
## Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you are asking is based on improper conditioning and the logistic model does not make such an estimate possible without enormous loss of information.  It is far more interpretable, and less sample dependent, to estimate an odds ratio that compares two specific values of fatigue.  Note that you are making a strong linearity (in the logits) assumption that can be easily relaxed with regression splines if your sample size is decent.

To elaborate on a point above, if you enroll subjects where very large or very small levels of fatigue, you will arbitrarily change the odds ratio that is based on incomplete conditioning (inequality instead of equality).

Answer (score 0):

Given your model, the odds of your response (called type in your code) is
$$\text{odds}=e^{ 0.3134 - 91.1171\times\text{fatigue} }$$
where you can plug in any reasonable value of fatigue that you want.

So for example, when fatigue is equal to 0, then your odds are

$$\text{odds}=e^{ 0.3134 - 91.1171\times0 }=e^{0.3134}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not exactly what I'm asking. I'd like to know the odds of type = 1, when fatigue is <= 0, not just = 0